# How to call local html from flutter and get arguments

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, dart

I build a flutter project and want to call js function from dart and get arguments.

It seems not very difficult but all I have tried not working.

Please help me.

main.dart

```
import 'dart:js';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
        callJavaScript();
      }, child: const Text('Hello')),
    );
  }

  void callJavaScript() {
    context.callMethod('greet', ['John']);
  }
}
```

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Call JavaScript function from Dart</title>
    <script>
    function greet(name) {
      console.log("Hello, " + name + "!");
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Call JavaScript function from Dart</h1>
<button onclick="greet('World')">Click me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

My project structure

[image]

console output
[image]